# Using Python to solve a vector differntial equation

Tags: python, vector, scipy, differential-equations

I am using python with scipy to solve differential equations with scalar second member, when i change it to a vector i couldn't make it right.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as si
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

t = np.linspace(0,1,500)
a = 2667613637.976072
phi = [-1, 0 , 1]
w = [10*np.pi, 5*np.pi, 10*np.pi]
beta = [1.25e-8, 1.12e-8, 1.18e-8]

def main():
    plt.plot(t, solver())

def get_g():
    idx = len(w)
    g = 0
    for i in range(0, idx):
        g += w[i]*beta[i]*np.cos(w[i]*(t+phi[i]))    
    return g
    
def diff(f, t):
    # a is a scalar, g is a sum of cos functions
    # the desired equation is dI/dt = a*I(t) + g(t)
    g = get_g()
    return ((f * a)  + g)

def solver():
    sol = si.odeint(diff, 0, t)
    return sol[:,0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the equation i'm trying to solve:

[image: Equation]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Trying to solve a differential equation that uses a sum of cos function in python, i have added the equation but i couldn't figure out how to solve it in python

Comment: Please make this into a [mre].

Comment: Do the values of  `a` and `beta` really have the correct scales? The solution is essentially `y(t)=5e-16*exp(2.6e9*t)`, without influence of the infinitesimal cosine terms. This exponential only has reasonable values for `t` up to around `1e-8`. You would need to set `atol=1e-12` or smaller, as the default value assumes a result scale of 1 to 10.

Comment: @Lehmann, `a` and `beta` are correct, the problem is an electric equation that needs to be solved in python, I am looking for a more generic solution, a and beta are not fixed (I just used those values for the sake of rectification with what LTSpice gives me and it gives me a sinus like wave form) i have tried putting t in `get_g` nothing changed, `g` is a 500 float array which `scipy.odeint` can't handle, it basically solves the DE for the first value of `g`, tried a workaround by making a function out of `g` but it didn't work either.

Comment: Then `a` should perhaps be negative, or get a minus sign in the ODE, forcing the solution to rapidly approach the equilibrium `g(t)/a` and stay close to it. I do not know what you did with `get_g`, I can not reproduce that with the changes I proposed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `t` that you want to use evaluating the function `get_g` is the `t` that has been passed to the `diff` function, not the time sample array that you defined at the beginning. It is in fact improbable (but not impossible) that any value of the time sample array but the first will be passed to the `diff` function.

So just add the parameter

```
def get_g(t):
    return sum( w[i]*beta[i]*np.cos(w[i]*(t+phi[i])) for i in range(len(w)) )
```

and then also in `diff` use `g=get_g(t)`.

---

Use `math` functions for scalar arguments to avoid unneeded overhead. Or make all arrays numpy so that you can replace explicit python loops by implicit numpy loops in numpy array operations.

```
phi = np.array([-1, 0 , 1])
w = np.array([10*np.pi, 5*np.pi, 10*np.pi])
beta = np.array([1.25e-8, 1.12e-8, 1.18e-8])

def get_g(t):
    return sum( w*beta*np.cos(w*(t+phi)) )  

def diff(f, t):
    # a is a scalar, g is a sum of cos functions
    # the desired equation is dI/dt = a*I(t) + g(t)
    g = get_g(t)
    return ((f * a)  + g)

def solver():
    sol = si.odeint(diff, 0, t, atol = 1e-18)
    return sol[:,0]
```

With these changes you should get a solution, however it diverges to infinity before reaching `t=1e-6`. This most likely means that the model needs some work.

Comment: Apparently scipy is unable to slove it since i have multiple cos functions summed together, the output of g is a 500 float array which can't be added in the function to solve it, @Lehmann your solution doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Your call is inside `diff` with `t` the argument of `diff`? If you call `get_g` with an array of length 500, you will also get a result of length 500